# Как передать объект в качестве аргумента функции?

Tags: python, функции, tkinter, gui

Не могу понять, как передать объект tkinter'a в метод модуля, если импортировать модуль полностью.

Исходник ***GUI*** (main.py) :

```
import tkinter as tk
import buttonFunctions

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1028x720')

# Виджет текстового поля и скролла слева
# master => root
frame_top = tk.Frame(root) # Верхний Frame
frame_bottom = tk.Frame(root) #Нижний Frame
text = tk.Text(frame_bottom, width=120, height=20)
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame_bottom, command=text.yview)
entryFileName = tk.Entry(frame_top)
buttonInsert = tk.Button(frame_top, text='Сохранить')
buttonGetText = tk.Button(frame_top, text='Открыть')
text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
buttonInsert.config(command=buttonFunctions.saveText(text, entryFileName))
buttonGetText.config(command=buttonFunctions.textFromOpenFile(text, entryFileName))


# Упаковщики
# smv.pack()
frame_top.pack()
frame_bottom.pack()
text.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X)
scroll.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
buttonGetText.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
entryFileName.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
buttonInsert.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Исходник функционала функционала (***buttonFunctions.py***) :

```
import tkinter as tk

def textFromOpenFile(text, entry):
    text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    filename = entry.get()

    with open(filename, 'r') as file_object:
        text.insert(1.0, file_object.read())

def saveText(text, entry):
    s = text.get(1.0, tk.END)
    filename = entry.get()

    with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
        file_object.write(s)
```

Отладка :

> File "main.py", line 17, in 
>   buttonInsert.config(command=buttonFunctions.saveText(text,
>   entryFileName))
>
> File "C:\Users\buttonFunctions.py", line 14, in saveText
>       with open(filename, 'w') as file_object: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: Выведите `print(filename)`. Кст, open создаст только файл, а если отсутствуют папки, то должна быть та ошибка

Comment: Вывести в конфиге кнопок или в главном файле с интерфейсом?

Comment: command=lambda:func помогло решить проблему

Comment: Необратил внимание на `buttonInsert.config(command=buttonFunctions.saveText(text, entryFileName))`, думал что именно с путями проблема :) а так, да, в command нужно передавать ссылку на функцию, но в текущим виде происходил просто вызов функции saveText и если бы функция удачно выполнилась, то в command попал результат ее выполнения, а именно `None`

Answer (score 1):

Решить проблему помогло добавление lambda - функции, которая просто вызывает функцию для кнопки.

```
buttonInsert.config(command=lambda:buttonFunctions.saveText(text, entryFileName))
buttonGetText.config(command=lambda:buttonFunctions.textFromOpenFile(text, entryFileName))
```